# Get product attribute block on category page: Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-page, product-listing

Here is the code display attribute block in PDP page,

```
    <?php
       echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes')
       ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')
       ->toHtml(); 
   ?>
```

If i put same code in PLP page i am getting error, how can i display my attribute block in PLP page.

Comment: Do you want specific attribute values or full file data on the listing page?

Comment: @Sumit https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98841/discussion-between-zus-and-sumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code in your list.phtml file to get the product's attribute data.

```
<?php
    $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

            if (!$_product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
            } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
            } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
            }

            if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                );
            }
        }
    }
?>
<?php if ($data) { ?>
    <?php 
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        $_category = null;
    ?>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($data as $_data): ?>
                    <?php if($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])=="No" || $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) =="Ei" | $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])=="???"): ?>
                    <?php else: ?> 
                        <?php if(strtolower($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label']))) == 'manufacturer'): ?>
                            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                            <td class="data">
                                <?php if($_category && $_category->getUrl() && strtolower($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label']))) == 'manufacturer'): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']); ?>">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
                                <?php if($_category && $_category->getUrl() && strtolower($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label']))) == 'manufacturer'): ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php endif; ?> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: everything okay, but N/A and empty attribut also display

Comment: Ok, just check the data coming with the condition as you did in PDP

Comment: sure, thank you

Comment: In my PDP page more number of attributes has values, in my PLP attributes values shown as N/A but attribute has values.

Comment: Configurable products attributes details showing wrong,  simple products attributes working good.  https://snipboard.io/GNat2L.jpg @Sumit

Comment: May i know why wring attributes details showing in configurable products. FYI simple products attributes details showing correct. @Sumit

Comment: Please check the product attribute data coming in the file, it'll only be displayed if the attribute is assigned to the product.

Comment: Configurable products have no attributes how to find then? Pls help me solve this issue?

Comment: You are using the above code to display the product attributes, right?

Comment: Yes, FYI simple products attributes showing good, but configurable products attributes values showing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to print the $data values coming for the configurable product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99991/discussion-between-zus-and-sumit).

Answer (score 2):

The block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` expects to get a product object out of the registry:

```
    function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
        }
        return $this->_product;
    }
```

A PLP doesn't register a product (since there are many), so the attributes block has no data to work with.

I tried setting a product in the `createBlock call`, but it looks like `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` is not written in a way that makes this possible. This is the code that *does not work for me*.

```
<?php
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes')
       ->setProduct($_product->load($_product->getId()))
       ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')
       ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Note that `$_product` here comes from the main loop in catalog/product/list.phtml. Since it is a member of a collection rather than a directly loaded product object, I had to load it explicitly. *This comes with a significant performance hit.*

You may be able to customize your Magento to make this work, but I don't think it is the best approach. It would be better to load the attributes that you want to see with the PLP product collection, i.e. via their "Used in Product Listing" setting. Then adapt the catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml template content for use in your PLP template, using the `$_product` object that is available.

Comment: I am getting error like :  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\wamp64\www\magepro\app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 101  sourcecode : https://paste.ofcode.org/kpv9VzmTu8ruU5KBD7nyHh

Comment: Apologies -- there was a typo in my sample code. It is updated to add a missing ")" after "->setProduct($_product->load($_product->getId())"

Comment: I also see that your template is calling "<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>".  This will slow down the page, because it is loading each product separately from the database, rather than using the product collection that is built in to the template. It should be possible to work around this. However, if not, I would suggest moving this line higher in the loop. This will allow you to skip loading the product again when calling setProduct in the attributes block.